# ASM: getting data from file DTA

Tags: assembly

This has to print a found file name, but it prints it with some of unlikely symbols. Any help?

```
mov dx,offset DTA
mov ah,1Ah
int 21h

mov dx, offset comex
xor cx, cx
mov ah,4Eh
int 21h
jc  exit

mov ah,40h 
mov bx, dst_fh 
mov cx,13
lea dx, DTA+30d 
int 21h
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . As well you should provide us an example of the incorrect output (and the output you expect). It would be nice if you mentioned what assembler you use, the environment etc. As it stands it looks like _MASM_ and a _DOS_ program. You should provide as much information as possible to have a chance of getting a solution.

Comment: Have you debugged this?  Does the 4E call set carry?  Instead of zeroing cx, what about setting it to 21h?

Answer (score 1):

When DOS fills the 13-byte long DTA field for the filename/extension it does so in a compact manner. This means that if the filename and its extension don't use the full space you end up with some garbage bytes behind the terminating zero. These are the weird characters that you observe! Look at these examples (**@** stands for the terminating zero):

```
in DTA            filespec
-------------     ------------
DOCUMENT.TXT@     DOCUMENT.TXT
SHORT.DOC@à&é     SHORT.DOC
F@&é"'(§è!çà)     F
```

The solution is to actually find the position of the terminating zero and setup CX accordingly.

```
lea dx, DTA+30
xor bx, bx
L1:
inc bx               ;There's always at least 1 character
cmp [DTA+30+bx],bh   ;BH=0
jne L1
mov cx, bx
mov bx, dst_fh
mov ah, 40h
int 21h
```

With this code you'll only send the actual filename+dot+extension.

Comment: This doesn't seem much of an an answer. You claim it is not clear (so effectively you need more info from the OP), and `perhaps` suggests you don't know what the issue is, but you are taking a guess based on the incomplete question. IMHO this should have been a comment to the question. I downvoted and flagged to close based on that.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I reworked my answer. Please reconsider your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you be using an filesystem with long name support, in this case the named returned by this DOS function will be converted to old 8.3 format.
Use the "dir /x" command to see the filenames showed is the same you has get with your code.
ps: this function return the filename with 13 bytes fixed size with name on first 8 chars and extention on 3 last ones and if your filename have less the 8 chars, white spaces will be placed to fill the first 8 chars.